# como poner una fila resaltada del resto con un click?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vuetify

hola necesito resaltar una sola fila al hacer click y que si apunto a alguna fila diferente se quede marcada la que hice click anteriormente, si cliqueo otra fila quede marcada ,para asi poder trabajar en una fila y no perderme de fila si hago scroll hacia abajo o arriba. vuetify remarca filas pero solo las apuntadas con el mouse, mi código:

```
<v-card>
<v-container>
<v-row>

<v-col
cols="4"
sm="4"
md="4"
>
<v-text-field
hide-details="auto"
v-model="showItem.idSolicitud"
label="ID"
readonly
></v-text-field>
</v-col>

 <v-col
cols="4"
sm="4"
md="4"
>
<v-text-field
hide-details="auto"
v-model="showItem.dni"
label="DNI"
readonly
></v-text-field>
</v-col>


</v-card>
</v-container>
</v-row>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score -1):

Los datatable de vuetify se pueden manipular usando métodos de vue revisa este código en codepen https://codepen.io/Juan-Carlos-MA/pen/yLoNevw?editors=1010 ahí encontraras mi solución la cual usa JavaScript para modificar los elementos de la tabla haciendo uso de los métodos de vue como son mounted() {} y methods: {} si tienes dudas consulta la pagina de vue sobre uso de métodos propios.

Primeramente se agrega estos métodos al código de la tabla HTML`

```
  :item-class="itemRowBackground"
  @click:row="asignarColor" 
  @mouseover:row="asignarColor"`
```

Después se define los estilos o colores en clases CSS para su uso

```
    .style-1 {
    background-color: white !important;
}

.style-2 {
    background-color: #00C853 !important;
}
```

Siguiendo con el código JavaScript como su nombre lo indica el método itemRowBackground() asigna el color a cada fila según su variable color que se anexo al array de datos de la tabla 1 para verde y 0 para blanco

```
    itemRowBackground: function (item) {
  if (item.color === 0) return "style-1";
  if (item.color === 1) return "style-2";
  return "style-1";
},
```

Mientras que el método  asignarColor(item) detecta el click en la tabla y envía el item clickeado al método para cambiar su color cambiando su variable color de 0 a 1 y viceversa.

```
  asignarColor(item) {
  this.desserts.forEach((element) => {
    if (element.dia == item.dia) {
      if(element.color==0){
        element.color = 1;
      }else{
        element.color=0;
      }
    }
  });
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si bien este enlace puede responder a la pregunta, es mejor incluir las partes esenciales de la respuesta aquí y proporcionar el enlace como referencia.  Las respuestas que son únicamente un enlace pueden dejar de ser válidas si la página vinculada cambia. - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/300064)

Comment: hola @Carlos estuve viendo tu codigo y me funciona lo de ponerle el color de fondo blanco , pero al hacer click para que se cambie de color no se cambia, queda del mismo color